# Implementing live search using Next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm new to Next js and im trying to implement a live search input field, I'm not sure if I have done things right if im violating some principles of next by not using getServerProps for this matter, what I have currently done is simply call an API and save the result in a simple state

```
  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const query = event.target.value;
    setQuery(query);
    if (event.target.value.length < 3) {
      setResults([]);
      return;
    }
    setLoading(true);
    fetchSearchResults(query);
  };


  const fetchSearchResults = async (paginate = "", query) => {
    if (query === "") {
      setResults([]);
    }
    const searchUrl = [uri];
    await axios
      .get(searchUrl)
      .then((res) => setResults(res.data.results))
      .catch((error) => setMessage("No data found"));
  };
```

Is there a better way to do such thing in next js(production ready)? Thanks

edit:
I found a way that could probably solve this by using getStaticProps with revalidate, however this is a component in the header that's on all pages and not a page, getStaticProps won't work here, is there a way around this?
To be clear I have a list of products, and the header contains a search bar that would function as an input for live search of these products